# How to recover LOST WORK resulting from the use of git?

Tags: git, git-commit, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree and what happened is that I clicked on "Commit", then added all changed files, but before committing I wanted to remove one of the files in order to commit it later.

I right-clicked on my file and was offered the following choices:

- Remove
- Discard
- Stop Tracking
- Unstage from index

[image]

I was really confused by those choices, I clicked "Discard" and now all the work done in this file was lost!!!

**PANIC MODE! How can I recover my changes in this file?**

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, it sounds to me that you really lost these changes. I'm not a "sourcetree" user, but I would expect "Discard" to, well, discard your changes. Now, if you have enabled some kind of "local history" in your IDE that works independently on Git, then you might be able to retrieve your changes that way. I know that Intellij IDEA has that enabled by default. Not sure about Eclipse or other tools. If you don't have that feature, than you should look into it. It's very neat to have an extra layer of security - it is also much more fine-grained than git commits.

Comment: Wow that's really scary!! I started using git to avoid data lost at first, and here I am prying on a desperate situation! BTW I'm using Netbeans (mostly default settings) any chance that I can recover my work from there?

Comment: **Which choice should I have used instead to remove one file from the commit?**

Comment: I don't know netbeans, but a quick google search shows that it does have a "local history" feature. You should check that. E.g. look at [this post](http://humansky.com/2012/05/netbeans-local-history-to-the-rescue/)

Comment: @Steinar thanks this helped! Git is not that safe after all, it's even dangerous to use it without mastering it! So how would I avoid such data lost in the future? What was the correct choice to use to remove a file before committing? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, git is a wonderful tool, but before you've committed your data it cannot help you with getting it back. Every source management tool has ways to discard current work and revert back to whatever state committed to the repository. So yes, when you start using a new source management tool, you should spend some time with a test repository to make yourself familiar with it.

Comment: @usernotfound: `Unstage from index` is what you probably wanted -- the 'index' in git is the set of files you're about to commit.

Comment: @usernotfound blaming your tools is not the best way to learn.  Git is not perfect but in this case I don't  see how git could have saved you from atlassians bad UI and your own too quick reaction (knowing what 'unstage' means is probably explained early on in every tutorial)

Comment: @jku Oh I'm not blaming my tools, where did you see that? Anyway, you must admit that the difference between `Remove`, `Discard`, `Stop Tracking` and `Unstage from index` is **really** not obvious! I don't know about git, but in regard to SourceTree they should really offer a simple "`Remove from commit`" choice that normal humans can understand.

Comment: @ChrisDodd thanks! If anyone of you wanna add an answer with @-ChrisDodd's information combined with @-Steinar's explanations I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 14):

If the file has been staged (it looks like yours was), a snapshot will exist is Git's database. We can get it back!

Git stores snapshots internally in the `.git/objects/` direction in your repository. Each object is stored in a file named for its hash, split into directories by the first 2 characters. Snapshots will exist here until they are either packed into files in `.git/objects/pack/` (which won't happen to a snapshot that was never part of a commit) or garbage collected (which will eventually happen to your missing file). The hard part will be figuring out which object it is.

To find the object, run

```
ls -lRt .git/objects
```

to get a list of all objects sorted by last modified time. Here's what my hypothetical repository looks like:

```
$ ls -lRt .git/objects

.git/objects/22:
total 4
-r--r--r-- 1 peter peter 17 Sep  1 11:18 3b7836fb19fdf64ba2d3cd6173c6a283141f78

.git/objects/f7:
total 4
-r--r--r-- 1 peter peter 17 Sep  1 11:09 0f10e4db19068f79bc43844b49f3eece45c4e8

.git/objects/54:
total 4
-r--r--r-- 1 peter peter 51 Sep  1 11:08 3b9bebdc6bd5c4b22136034a95dd097a57d3dd

.git/objects/e8:
total 4
-r--r--r-- 1 peter peter 134 Sep  1 11:08 e8417380c89509ec1e5b67c15469547a4489c2

.git/objects/e6:
total 4
-r--r--r-- 1 peter peter 15 Sep  1 11:08 9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
```

Run

```
git cat-file -p <hash>
```

on candidate objects until you find the one you're missing. Remember to add the 2 characters from the directory name to the hash. In my case, if I'm interested in the file from 11:09

```
git cat-file -p f70f10
```

Happy hunting.

Comment: Thank you for that, but there are literally thousands of objects and it seems humanly impossible for me to find the unique state of that specific file manually... Maybe with the help of a good search tool that provides visual results... Does such tool exist?

Comment: I was hoping the timestamp would be sufficient. That said, [git-fsck(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html) could definitely help here. See if `git fsck --lost-found` takes less work to sift through.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans I have successfully recovered files by using its history options to restore the files that sourcetree deleted. If you right click on the project and go to history, there is an option to revert deleted files. I know this question is a bit old but hope this helps who ever else comes across it.

Answer (score 0):

In SourceTree - assuming you have some commit history of the file you are looking for - you can recover some or all of your work after having "Removed" a file in either of two ways:
1) select the file in the "staged index" area or the "working tree" area. In the detail window SourceTree will show you the entire file (since you removed it its entire content is "changed"). You can then copy/paste the entire content of that window into a text editor and insert the file back into your working copy.
2) select the file in the "staged index" or "working tree" area and right click to access the Reset to Commit function. You then select which Commit you want to revert that file to and click OK.

Comment: Hi Fabrice, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't fully solve the problem because I didn't lose the file, I just lost the latest changes that I made to that file – and this is what I'm trying to recover. Furthermore, if any SourceTree developer is reading this, I suggest that SourceTree displays a warning that clearly state what is being "Discarded" and that this action is definitive and irrevocable. An optimal UX/solution would be to add the possibility to cancel any action taken in the software via an "Undo" button.