# Lost a git commit

Tags: linux, git, gitorious

I have the hash for a git commit I made a few weeks ago.  I tried checking it out but it says that the hash "did not match any file(s) known to git".  I also looked for it in git reflog, but don't see it there.  I don't see the earliest commits I made in reflog either.

I couldn't find the missing commit in my remote repository in Gitorious either.  However, I do see the earliest commits I made in Gitorious, just not the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the commit no longer exists in your database, which is unfortunate. Start with a `git lost-found` just in case you have the hash wrong.

If it disappeared because it was garbage collected, you're out of luck. If it disappeared for any other reason (disk corruption, file system bug, etc.), you may still be able to find the blobs that were in that commit.

`git fsck` can tell you if there are any problems with git's internal database. If that doesn't turn up anything, try this: [How to recover LOST WORK resulting from the use of git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548455/how-to-recover-lost-work-resulting-from-the-use-of-git)

Comment: so old commits get garbage collected?  How do you make sure to keep old commits and do you know how to tell what is the retention period before garbage collection occurs?

Comment: @user994165 Just to clarify, only unreachable objects are garbage collected. Commits that are an ancestor of some branch are reachable and will never be garbage collected. But if, for example, you make a commit and then 'undo' it by resetting to the parent, that commit may be garbage collected.